# Using Bootstrap Progress bar to Display mysql data in Multiple progress bars (3 bars)

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Issue page which generate these numbers from mySQL. These numbers keeps changing based on the issue raised, on-hold or closed.

```
$opened - 8  
$onHold - 3  
$completed - 60
```

I want to place them in the **Bootstrap progress bar**. How do i do that.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 15%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 30%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**
This explains https://stackoverflow.com/a/46082290/5413283 a single bar, i am looking for 3 bars.

#### here's what i tried

```
<section>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $completed; ?>%;" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $bal; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><?php echo $completed; ?></div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-danger text-right pr-2" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $opened; ?>%;" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $output; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><?php echo $opened; ?></div>
        <div class="progress-bar bg-warning text-right pr-2" role="progressbar" style="width: <?php echo $onHold; ?>%;" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $output; ?>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><?php echo $onHold; ?></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Here's the output**
how do i fill the progress bar (without the gray area)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the php variables into you html, you can use php tags and echo the variables in the desired locations.

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:<?php echo $opened; ?>%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:<?php echo $onHold; ?>%"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width:<?php echo $completed; ?>%"></div>
</div>
```

We don't know if those values are percentage values or if some calculation is required to prepare the data.

---

Update: To fill the full meter to 100% using the 3 values, you will need to find the factor that will take the total to 100%.  Like this: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81ba6e8cb139478055d81640ea203c223d76dd31))

```
$opened = 5;
$onHold = 22;
$completed = 1;
$total_of_3 = $opened + $onHold + $completed;
$factor =  100 / $total_of_3;

echo "New opened = " , $opened * $factor , "\n";
echo "New onHold = " , $onHold * $factor , "\n";
echo "New completed = " , $completed * $factor;
```

Output:

```
New opened = 17.857142857143
New onHold = 78.571428571429
New completed = 3.5714285714286
```

Of course, if you want to be exactly 100% on the nose, or you want to do some rounding of numbers, you can calculate (and round) `$new_opened` and `$new_onHold`, then just use `100 - $new_opened + $new_onHold` to determine the perfect `$new_completed`.

Comment: Those are mysql `COUNT()`, Do i have to convert into percentage before output on the style.width ? Something like the one mentioned in the reference link `[total active=1] / [total records] * 100 = [percent from 0 - 100]`

Comment: Well, the meters are out of 100, so yes you will need to perform some calculations.

Comment: The one mentioned in the reference link works for 2 bar. But is there a way to get the output for three. Not sure if this make sense..

Comment: I have already tried your approach. I have updated the code with the result.

Comment: I misunderstood your edit at first.  Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score -1):

A progress bar is to show what percent of a task is completed. To do this, you will need current value, floor and ceiling values.

If you can get such numbers, use a progress bar or you should use something like the bootstrap badge with number count.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  Tasks <span class="badge badge-light">9</span>
  <span class="sr-only">unread messages</span>
</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```